# What is the definition of ''geometrically irreducible closed curve''?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

In the algebraice geometry, one says about "geometrically irreducible closed curve" over field $k$. For example, the theorem 5.4.5 (pp. 147) of ''Heights in Diophantine Geometry'' of E. Bombieri wrote that "Let $C$ be a geometrically irreducible closed curve in $\mathbb{G}^n_m$ defined over a number field $K$, not a translate of a subtorus of $\mathbb{G}^n_m$, and let $\Gamma$ be any finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb{G}^n_m(\bar{K})$. Then $C \cap \Gamma$ is an effectively computable finite set."

I think it means that a curve $(C)$ which is geometrically irreducible and closed over $k$. This means that

- If $(C)$ is represented by $F(x,y) = 0$ with $F(x,y) \in k[X, Y]$ then $F(x,y)$ is irreducible over $\bar{k}[x,y]$ where $\bar{k}$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.
- In the graph of $(C)$, the beginning and end points are the same.

**My question:** Is my definition true? Are there other definition of this problem?

Thank you very much for your interests!

Comment: Not every curve can be defined by some $F(x,y)\in k[X,Y]$ (not every curve is a plane curve).

Comment: If $n=2$, your idea of geom. irreducible would be correct. As @Wojowu points out, not every curve is plane. But the idea is the same, $C$ is not geometrically irreducible if there are $C_1,C_2$ curves over $\bar k$ with $C=C_1\cup C_2$. Closed is unnecessary in this context but means that you haven't taken out any points.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, thank you so much. Of course, you're right. But I am saying that "If it is represented ...." .

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Thank you so much for your nice comments. Can you give an example to explain the differences of "geometrically irreducible" and "irreducible". Why don't you need to use "Closed" in here?

Comment: Consider a curve defined by $x^2-2y^2$ over $\mathbb Q$. It is easily seen to be irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x,y]$, but in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})[x,y]$ it factors as $(x-sqrt{2}y)(x+\sqrt{2}y)$, so the curve can be written as the union of the curves defined by those linear factors.

Comment: @Wojowu OK, thank you so much! Your example is very nice and clear.